# How to change Text value when a button is clicked in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have three composable buttons and a composable Text() and I want to change the text value of the Text() composable to a particular value when a certain composable button is clicked.

I know how to achieve this in `xml` by using `setText()` and I've tried to solve this by using `MutableStateOf()` but I keep getting it wrong somewhere.

[image: something like this]

Comment: Please add your code to get explanation of what’re you doing wrong

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
// if you have issue with remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
```

```
@Composable
fun ChangeText() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Click a button") }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        Text(text)

        Button(onClick = { text = "Button 1 Clicked" }) {
            Text(text = "Button 1")
        }
        Button(onClick = { text = "Button 2 Clicked" }) {
            Text(text = "Button 2")
        }
        Button(onClick = { text = "Button 3 Clicked" }) {
            Text(text = "Button 3")
        }
    }
}
```